# How can I find what services are offered in a WSDL file?

Tags: web-services, wsdl

I am a SOAP/WebServices newbie, and have been given a WSDL file that has a bunch of web services that I can connect to.

What is the easiest way to parse this and show me what services are offered, and what the input and output parameters are that are required?  I really don't want anything more than this, but for whatever reason I can't seem to google an answer.

The closest I've gotten is using wsdl2java from Apache Axis, however it creates a whole bunch of Java objects.  What I really want is very basic, which is give me a list of all of the services available, and the input/output parameters.

Does such a thing exist or do I need to build this myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without installing anything I suppose this link would work but it requires that your WSDL be web accessible...

http://www.validwsdl.com/

Other online parsers may be better. Personally I'd recommend installing Eclipse with the web services plugin or the demo version of SOAPSonar, but if you only need to peek at what a WSDL offers without having to dig through the XML, then the above link might be an acceptable option.